# C function to fill an array with strings from user input

Tags: arrays, c, function

I am stuck on a programming assignment in C. The user has to enter a number specifying the size of an array no bigger than 10 elements which will store the names of students. This must be done in a separate function from the main function called getNames. Each name can be up to 14 characters and getNames must be invoked from within the main function. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void getNames(char *a, int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Enter a name: ");
        scanf("%s", &a[i]);
    } 

}

void printNames(char *a, int n){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", &a[i]);
    }
}

void main(){
    int num; //number of names in array 'names'
    printf("Num of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char names[num][15]; //each name is 14 characters plus
                         //a null character
    getNames(names[num], num);
    printNames(names[num], num);

}
```

The code compiles and runs without syntax errors but the array is not filled correctly. For example:

```
Num of students: 5
Enter a name: Jeb
Enter a name: Bob
Enter a name: Bill
Enter a name: Val
Enter a name: Matt
```

returns:

```
JBBVMatt
BBVMatt
BVMatt
VMatt
Matt
```

Clearly there is an issue writing to the array but I am not sure what it is.

For this assignment our professor was adamant that we cannot use any global variables. His wording was rather vague about how we should implement this. My first thought would be to move the for loop in getNames into the main function and just calling getNames repeatedly but I would like a solution that incorporates that into getNames. I'm new to C, having mostly dealt with Java so please bear with me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do following

1. Method

in `main` function call as below

```
getNames(names, num);
printNames(names, num);
```

and change the functions as below

```
void getNames(char (*a)[15], int n) 
{
   ...
}

void printNames(char (*a)[15], int n)
{
   ...
}
```

2. Method , in main calls remain same

`void getNames(char a[5][15], int n)`

and

`void printNames(char a[5][15], int n)`

But instead of using hard values better to use `#define`  row and col sizes

Answer (score 1):

If the code you have posted is exactly the code you are using, then it is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing a memory location that your program does not own: `getNames(names[num], num);`.
Array indexing in C goes from `0` to `n-1`. (or from `names[0]`-`names[num-1]`)  Same in other similar calls.

next issue is the function prototypes to accommodate;

```
char names[num][15];
```

The function needs to send the address of an array of arrays.  See edits on code to show the difference.

Next issue are the following statements, see comments after each

```
getNames(names[num], num);//names[n] points to memory beyond what is owned.
                          //should point to address of beginning of memory &names[0]
printNames(names[num], num);//ditto
```

Working code example, see edits to explain:

```
//void getNames(char *a, int n){//change *a to either a[][15] or (*a)
void getNames(char a[][15], int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Enter a name: ");
        scanf("%s", a[i]);
    } 

}

 //void printNames(char *a, int n){ //change *a to either a[][15] or (*a)
 void printNames(char a[][15], int n){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}

void main(){
    int num; //number of names in array 'names'
    printf("Num of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char names[num][15]; //each name is 14 characters plus
                         //a null character
    //getNames(names[num], num);//names[n] points to memory beyond what is owned.
    //printNames(names[num], num);//ditto
    getNames(&names[0], num);
    printNames(&names[0], num);

}
```

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! This worked out fine for me. I really appreciate the input. We haven't even covered memory allocation yet so this assignment feels like I'm in a cave without a flashlight trying to feel my way through.

Comment: I would swap `a` and `n` in the parameters, then you could write (assuming a modern compiler) `void getNames(int n, char a[n][15]) { .... }`, which may be easier to grasp for a beginner.

Comment: @HAL9000 - Because there [is no guarantee](https://www.embedded.com/evaluating-function-arguments/) that function arguments are recognized in any particular order, It is undefined. eg if  `char a[n][15]` were seen in a call to `getNames` before `int n`, then `n` would be undefined.  But otherwise, it would be a good idea.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, the order of evaluating parameters before calling a function is not defined, but as soon as the function is called, all the parameter values are defined. And modern c (AFAIK) does allow an integer argument in a function parameter be used as array size in another, but the size parameter must come before the array parameter.

Comment: Some additional explanation: There is nothing in `getNames(int n, char a[n][15])` that demands that `n` has been calculated before `a`, as long as `a` isn't referenced before `n` exist. And that doesn't happen before inside the function where both `n` and `a` are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @HAL9000 -  I think you just want to assert your style here.  There is nothing logically or syntactically compelling to change the parameters.  It is clearly more common to see size follow array as function parameters.

Comment: @ryyker, Yes it is more common to see size follow array as function parameters. But when using VLA,  size must come before array. And you are also right, there is  technically no need to use VLA here, so technically no need to swap parameters. I just think VLA in this case may be easier to understand for a beginner, just a personal opinion.